# CSS check box, how to make an item unchecked only if another one is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create some sort of slide show based on `CSS Checkbox`. So corresponding data is visible when its button is pressed.
But the issue is the data disappear if the button is pressed again. I want to make it in a way what once a button is pressed and its data is visible, it only disappear when another button is pressed. So it won't be on and off but on unless another button is pressed.

Here is the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/a38nj8kf/1/)

```js
$.fn.MP = function(options) {
  var settings = $.extend({
    // These are the defaults
    text: ""
  }, options);

  $(this).on("click tap", "input", function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find("input").prop("checked", false);
  });
};

// dynamically-generate id/for values
$('div.panel').each(function(index, el) {
    var $panel = $(el);
    var panelId = $panel.attr('id');
    var $panelBottom = $('div.panelBottom', $panel);

    $('div.panelTop > div > input', $panel).each(function(indexInput, elInput) {
        var $input = $(elInput);
        var inputId = panelId + '-box-' + indexInput;

        $input.attr('id', inputId);
        $('label:nth(' + indexInput + ')', $panelBottom).attr('for', inputId);
    });
});

$("#item1").MP({});
$("#item2").MP({});
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.panelTop > div div {
  display: none;
}

.panelTop > div input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div {
  display: block;
}

.panel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.panel > .panelTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 49px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}

.panel > .panelBottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.panel > .panelTop > div div {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.panel > .panelBottom > div {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  float: right;
  margin: 9px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel" id="item1">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>1.2</div>
      <div>1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <div>2.1</div>
      <div>2.2</div>
      <div>2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <div>3.1</div>
      <div>3.2</div>
      <div>3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="item2">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>1.2</div>
      <div>1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <div>2.1</div>
      <div>2.2</div>
      <div>2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <div>3.1</div>
      <div>3.2</div>
      <div>3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now in the above example the data corresponding to button `1` is visible. if you press the same button again, its data disappears. I want it to work in a way that the button only shows data and data only disappears when a different button is pressed.

Any idea to achieve that?

Comment: That sounds like a radio input group to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `input[type=radio]` instead.

```js
$.fn.MP = function(options) {
  var settings = $.extend({
    // These are the defaults
    text: ""
  }, options);

  $(this).on("click tap", "input", function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find("input").prop("checked", false);
  });
};

// dynamically-generate id/for values
$('div.panel').each(function(index, el) {
  var $panel = $(el);
  var panelId = $panel.attr('id');
  var $panelBottom = $('div.panelBottom', $panel);

  $('div.panelTop > div > input', $panel).each(function(indexInput, elInput) {
    var $input = $(elInput);
    var inputId = panelId + '-box-' + indexInput;

    $input.attr('id', inputId);
    $('label:nth(' + indexInput + ')', $panelBottom).attr('for', inputId);
  });
});

$("#item1").MP({});
$("#item2").MP({});
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.panelTop > div div {
  display: none;
}
.panelTop > div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div {
  display: block;
}
.panel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.panel > .panelTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 49px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
.panel > .panelBottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.panel > .panelTop > div div {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.panel > .panelBottom > div {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  float: right;
  margin: 9px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel" id="item1">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="radio" checked>
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>1.2</div>
      <div>1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>2.1</div>
      <div>2.2</div>
      <div>2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>3.1</div>
      <div>3.2</div>
      <div>3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="item2">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="radio" checked>
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>1.2</div>
      <div>1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>2.1</div>
      <div>2.2</div>
      <div>2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>3.1</div>
      <div>3.2</div>
      <div>3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

As a side note, you can take advantage of the CSS `counter()` function here.  *(Everything is declared at the bottom of the CSS for clarity).*

```js
$.fn.MP = function(options) {
  var settings = $.extend({
    // These are the defaults
    text: ""
  }, options);

  $(this).on("click tap", "input", function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find("input").prop("checked", false);
  });
};

// dynamically-generate id/for values
$('div.panel').each(function(index, el) {
  var $panel = $(el);
  var panelId = $panel.attr('id');
  var $panelBottom = $('div.panelBottom', $panel);

  $('div.panelTop > div > input', $panel).each(function(indexInput, elInput) {
    var $input = $(elInput);
    var inputId = panelId + '-box-' + indexInput;

    $input.attr('id', inputId);
    $('label:nth(' + indexInput + ')', $panelBottom).attr('for', inputId);
  });
});

$("#item1").MP({});
$("#item2").MP({});
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.panelTop > div div {
  display: none;
}
.panelTop > div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div {
  display: block;
}
.panel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.panel > .panelTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 49px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
.panel > .panelBottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.panel > .panelTop > div div {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.panel > .panelBottom > div {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  float: right;
  margin: 9px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.panelTop {
  counter-reset: my-counter;
}
.panelTop > div {
  counter-increment: my-counter;
  counter-reset: sub-counter;
}
.panelTop > div > div {
  counter-increment: sub-counter;
}
.panelTop > div > div::before {
  content: counter(my-counter)"." counter(sub-counter)" ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel" id="item1">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="radio" checked>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="item2">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="radio" checked>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### EDIT:

To take full advantage of the radio group, and for this to work without:

```
  $(this).on("click tap", "input", function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find("input").prop("checked", false);
  });
```

You have to give the same value to the attribute `name` on each radio in the input group.

```js
$.fn.MP = function(options) {
  var settings = $.extend({
    // These are the defaults
    text: ""
  }, options);

};

// dynamically-generate id/for values
$('div.panel').each(function(index, el) {
  var $panel = $(el);
  var panelId = $panel.attr('id');
  var $panelBottom = $('div.panelBottom', $panel);

  $('div.panelTop > div > input', $panel).each(function(indexInput, elInput) {
    var $input = $(elInput);
    var inputId = panelId + '-box-' + indexInput;

    $input.attr('id', inputId);
    $('label:nth(' + indexInput + ')', $panelBottom).attr('for', inputId);
  });
});

$("#item1").MP({});
$("#item2").MP({});
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.panelTop > div div {
  display: none;
}
.panelTop > div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div {
  display: block;
}
.panel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.panel > .panelTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 49px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
.panel > .panelBottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.panel > .panelTop > div div {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.panel > .panelBottom > div {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  float: right;
  margin: 9px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.panelTop {
  counter-reset: my-counter;
}
.panelTop > div {
  counter-increment: my-counter;
  counter-reset: sub-counter;
}
.panelTop > div > div {
  counter-increment: sub-counter;
}
.panelTop > div > div::before {
  content: counter(my-counter)"." counter(sub-counter)" ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel" id="item1">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="item1" checked>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="item1">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="item1">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="item2">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="item2" checked>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="item2">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="item2">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add that a group of radios will act as desired by sharing the same `name`.

Comment: @zer00ne Done. Thanks for the improvement.